# Ajax request with custom header to other domain WebApi

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am tring to send request to other domain WebApi using JQuery Ajax method. It works without header. But when I send a Ajax request with custom header I am getting "405->Method Not Allowed" Error in browser.

**Does not Works**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:53103/api/Values",
        headers: { "ABC123": "ABC abc 123" }
       });
```

This call hit to *ValuesController* Constructor but does not hit to *Get()* method.

**This Works**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:53103/api/Values"
       });
```

This code works without any problem.

**Server Side WebAPI**

```
 public class ValuesController : ApiController
 {
    public ValuesController()
    {}

    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
 }
```

On server I have vanilla WebApi project. I also have enabled CORS in system.webServer section.

```
  <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers"  value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

As I mentioned before after enabling CORS in web.config I can access data using simple ajax request but when I send ajax request with headers I am getting "405 Method not allowed" error.
What I should do so that I can send request with headers to other domain WebApi.

Comment: can you share a fiddler output?

Comment: @YishaiGalatzer with fiddler everything is working. it is only when I am trying with JQuery.

Comment: You can use fiddler to capture network traffic as well as compose requests. Please capture the traffic from your browser to the service and paste it. You can see the traffic on the left pane.

Comment: I have the same problem, do you know any solution?

Comment: I am facing same problem, any one has that solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        beforeSend: function (request)
        {
            request.setRequestHeader("ABC123", "ABC abc 123");
        },
        url:"http://localhost:53103/api/Values"
      });
```